# What is the purpose of this extra capacitor in this opamp low pass filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter, hc-sr04, dc-blocking

I'm trying to follow along with [this blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20170308062234/http://uglyduck.ath.cx/ep/archive/2014/01/Making_a_better_HC_SR04_Echo_Locator.html) reverse engineering the HC-SR04 ultrasonic distance sensor.

The signal from the receiving transducer is amplified, filtered, and then amplified again.

On the filter, there is a 1 nF cap C4 between the signal and inverting input which I believe is a DC block. There is a second 1 nF cap C3 between the signal and op amp output.

What is the purpose of C3?

The expected signal frequency is 40 kHz.

[image]

Comment: The shown parts values give a bandpass center frequency of app. fo=19.8 kHz.

Comment: Why did you think it was 40kHz?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

### What is the purpose of C3?

(corrected) Pardon my poor engineeringlish.

[I meant Negative Inductance not -L.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKAA8RDJtwjOEIYFMRAAWECnEALOgBtZAe3adIKXuTzNwuMROlzFAHQDOAMwBOCgLYmAKgoB2ATxMBRVwHIMCZcxwhsDDxwUQRCAM1dMHEAYwBDczpTAFd5F2MAB1TjOhMAFxkTAGUABQARWxMYugc8xJMAdwBLAoVkvJMrBQA3JocAcxMW6GVRUjFhEDxIclFsNXFokFcEgpMFYxim%20Ti8vsHjPvXzACMWgH5jk2Nkh2uMvod9kziTntyc1alzliLwISouEWkFEgJBUHAIFMcVkOQhKBYDSmhHEmDUYBBVDRUERyFBEjwwQx%20OxkFxxMB2HCFICaBxHAxVIkmF4cwkOlR4gAqgAxADyJlkcQcABNnsZHG4vuTIAhyBj5bKNDwyUiMXLtCJ1fKUCqZRqwIQeNrwAgkKqQEFxKCqFaJBg1GSYsjrXAQMRRK6qFQwIx5dAENgzaJhCg0MRCIQgirYJBWP1LQgFqJgt4FiiIWSwBhbXgvYmFm61HSbbQoNBWEiPeJ5lQ8BnaziE-Wa3SWwEmd6WOYXWI3XabRCMXAZfjsEyaYOLdWAkn3Z6%2012EybdUgVwJM93LXn7Wp26TkCPZL3se3G96K%20W4GBA2bCBjiJQU9mbzi4vOaxPMR3wlqkEw13gICLyA7BmDlLhCAIOZpmwHcfWAlh3xNMA8EVA0MEEH1-1fYcgMzQ94C3GdB0nN0EJHPl-jpIF-iggJwS7UEeE0akMF-BdJG9CgAH0UR4yAeLmM0eIQATYzgMhCDCFAxMElBRJ47AWGY5AwgCejmB3OZHXAYg%20NEAShKDMS5NjQhZKMhSwH05SFHtThxCoYSkHNS8fRYIA) L is always a positive interger, with positive reactance, while C is a negative reactance, unless used in an impedance converter with feedback.
*(so always think in terms of impedance)*

**C4 is an active inductor or negative capacitor** as the negative impedance converter (NIC) while **C3 is the active capacitor or negative inductor** using negative feedback as an integrator by subtracting its response from the input 820 ohm source impedance. (1k // 6k2)  While C2 has very little effect and C4 in series with C3 are equivalent to a passive L//C to virtual AC grounds. (Vin- and Vout)  The NIC converts the series C3:C4 notch filter into a BPF using NIC negative feedback via Vin-. *[(I hope this is clear)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Negative_impedance_converter)*

C2 is a weak integrator pole 2 orders of magnitude in f above the BPF, just before the possible GBW limits to normalize the filter variance with IC's having tolerances on a 5~10 MHz GBW or so as to reduce the peak gain variance yet drop it by a fixed amount 3dB. It could improve phase margin on IC's with << 60 deg. *that is my hunch.*

[image]

[The actual frequency is about 20 kHz with a gain of 12 dB.](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%20213674106.62116134%0Aw%20296%20336%20256%20336%200%0Aw%20208%20280%20208%20336%200%0Aw%20352%20344%20352%20336%200%0Aw%20352%20336%20352%20280%200%0AO%20352%20280%20392%20280%200%0A170%20160%20336%20128%20336%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0Ac%20208%20336%20256%20336%200%201e-9%200%0Ac%20208%20280%20256%20280%200%201.0000000000000003e-9%200%0Ar%20296%20280%20296%20336%200%2075000%0Aw%20296%20280%20352%20280%200%0Ar%20160%20336%20208%20336%200%206200%0Ar%20208%20336%20208%20392%200%201000%0Ag%20208%20392%20208%20400%200%0Aa%20296%20344%20352%20344%202%2015%20-15%20100000000%0Ag%20296%20352%20296%20392%200%0Ac%20256%20336%20256%20280%200%201.1999999999999999e-11%200%0Aw%20256%20280%20296%20280%200%0A)
It is mainly a 2nd order LC parallel resonant filter with some R ratio gain.  The 12 pF reduces the Q  peaking from 15 dB to 12 dB.

The GBW must be at least 4 MHz and preferably 10 MHz minimum  from my RoT (Rule of Thumb).

GBW = Qmax^2 * Av * fo= 64 * 3.3 * 20 kHz

**If we had to use an inductor, it would be quite large in physical size to achieve a low ESR <= 10 mohm and 50x times the cost of a cap, roughly.**
[image]

[ref](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/taiyo-yuden/NS10145T102MNA/2774688) This is a rough approximation of a similar LC filter.

[image]

This does not mean you can pass 10 Amps thru the Inductance "C4". [Something might explode.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICM0DMiBM64A45kSlgOwBsJIeFFEcApgLSKIBQAHiNiUSOhiAJxwEvBABYe4gE4MAJpICGAdwB2bECTDok6btiZIUEcenEALWgBsLAewA6AZwBmk6wFsHAFWvKAng4Ci-gDkRHBqTEQoIChE2EiicOQoeiDiiOIAxvLSjgCuVn72AA759rQOAC7mDgDKAAoAIh4OGbTKFdIOigCWVda5FQ6u1gBu3coA5g69kGqi-Pyp6IvYYNyihKnxIP7ZVQ7W9hndVvIV41P24weSAEa9APw3Dva5yi9F48oXDvK3o%20UyntTA9mDUkBgIIY0mBRFDYeAkCBHPILGVEehmIoOCRjEQtPxRHitGAsUhYRB0Ng4ogKTx8eAybS4dEUORmVD0BBSexaWyeDptBseIYtiYQABVABiAHkHBZ5MoZD97N4AsCmWA4NxaTqtbooqTsbTtQZFiadehDZrTYgSFELUghIzsbFxHCIG76STmBkce6YAIialAxBEAwdZAubrQihRAQ4BsGWBoPhmBMQKEtES4lnUrjEaTEERPdgA564NnA4hyUZYFQU1qyYTxIQIJxW1zGRmO9Eu72UPzucxJP6Q6Xy4jaTBNSzB%20y6R6XUHW5WV%20Pu%20TTVaEI6sDXh6OvTotL2T1PYMwLGPzwOu9zIAfU1b%20Pg9Ha1rxNNb5Ov5%20S535c0EEYXdYHAiB6EbWB0jjQRmTgFBBBIEwEDDCDmF-R1EGwPVbSIGtaSdEBQNrcDCzImdRxbDcOQ3dCZxlCEu2hCESDiVjhzhKINBpDRM35TBxBoAB9XERLAESNkTETaQk1MYH4UhEiwCSRPQES4BElARIAGQOAZmG49QwDiExPX5TikH4MTRDU0ROBITT5JgFCtMkjTEBsnSADV%20gqIywB40y%20wspIywxSTxMkhyyBc2BSGWJCEjQVToMU5S3LUjSuW0kSfPGehfTHDYtDo0qpwjEiUytZJcM4NYS1xJhyGglhjUXatF02I0SsDXsKtJP0aPPGi20q%20huEYSAYlM0RYmwfhVi8ohhTa5tg3POjzx5Dg4EWGIEH4XholiLZ0hAAAiABhURLocf43DUXAa3QEga04KI3vdbZdJQNR4NSU1%20BIMR%20LScRrv%206x6SQVrUhQZ0iJTA8kGYIA) (LOL)

But the Op Amp draws current from supply to do the same as the inductor, except this is an inverting NIC. or INIC.

Comment: @Tony Stewart, with all respect, I cannot follow your explanation. Of course, you can replace the shown active RC circuit with a corresponding LC circuit. Such a step is always possible. However, how can you say that "C3 is an active inductor"? In the original circuit the capacitor C3 provides a LOW-pass function to the circuit (and C4 acts as a highpass). But in the LC equivalent, the inductor is responsible for the HIGH-pass properties (and it attenuates low frequencies). So the capacitor C3 does exactly the opposite as mentioned by you.

Comment: Negative Impedance Converter logic says YOU CAN define a Cap C4 as an active Inductor.  C3 is obviously an integrator cap was my err. (BrainFart @LvW)

Comment: But where do you see an impedance converter NIC? More than that, it is the input impedance of the whole NIC circuit (and NOT the capacitor alone) which can behave like a lossy inductance. I think, such a view has nothing to do with the circuit under question.

Comment: With respect to the corrected version of the above answer: The reference to a negative impedance converter (NIC) is not correct.  A short look into the linked document reveals that the bandpass circuit under discussion has no relation to an NIC block.

Comment: More than that: I can read that " C4 is an active inductor or negative capacitor" and "C3 is the active capacitor or negative inductor ".  Such a claim needs an explanation. I wonder how a negative capacitor can have a frequency response like an inductor?

Comment: @LvW I am surprised you don't know this.  Did you read the ref link? That explains all the types of NIC. from the simplest Av=-Xf/Xin  so Xin the impedance of Xin is inverted to create the output that models a passive inductor

Comment: the two C's form a series notch to the input with negative feedback inverted to become a BPF.   Xc= - XL ispso facto

Comment: Quote: "C4 is an active inductor or negative capacitor". Again I ask you: How can an active inductor be identical to a negative capacitor? Does this mean that the impedance jwL is equal to (-1/jwC=j/wC) ? No - of course, not! When you read again the third comment above, you will see that I know something about VNIC and INIC. But the main point is: The whole story about the NIC has nothing to do with the original question and the bandpass circuit under discussion. Why did you even bring that up?

Comment: Clarification (for someone who is not familiar with NIC-techniques):  An NIC is an active network (opamp and 3 passive parts). The input impedance at one NIC-port can be identical to the input impedance of a negative inductance (-jwL) if one of the three passive parts is selected as a capacitor C. But this does not mean that this C "is a negative inductor". I hope this clarifies the subject.

Comment: Here is the simplest case of an active Inductance XL  https://tinyurl.com/cduhetd6 -Xc using in a highpass filter

Comment: In terms of resistance or reactance controlled spectral shaped filters, we use the properties of impedance ratios with a suitable active gain (error) amplifier  to achieve negative resistance using loss with negative feedback to get gain.  Also to achieve an active inductors from the insertion C4 capacitor to resonate with C3, the integrating cap. in series. Thus the inverting NIC turns a notch filter at the error input Vin- into a bandpass output.

Comment: @LvW I think you meant to correct my terms of impedance or inductance  rather than the misconstrued negative integer value of L.  Are you in agreement yet ? If so pls upvote to indicate agreement.   https://tinyurl.com/yf69jkcp

Comment: I am afraid the whole discussion about NIC and its use will confuse the questioner (user 364952) because it has - as I have mentioned before - nothing to do with his question about a multi-feedback-bandpass.

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/yj9tj5j6  It has everything to do with why multiple feedback RC filters eliminate inductors. It's an Alternative Perspective that needs to be learnt but requires more thought than just a label.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to EE.SE.

The block highlighted in red is an active bandpass filter, which C3 and C4 are part of. See https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html under Infinite Gain Multiple Feedback Active Filter. Presumably it is tuned to 40 kHz. I haven't checked but you are welcome to plug the component values into the formula given in the link.

C2 rolls off the gain at high frequency (>> 40 kHz) to improve the stability of the filter i.e. prevent it oscillating.

Comment: The filter is stable - even without C2. It is the only purpose of C2 to increase the damping for very large frequencies. C2 adds a lowpass characteristic to the bandpass (3rd-order damping for high frequencies far above the bandpass center frequency.)

Comment: The center frequency of the given circuit is app. at fo=19.8 kHz

Answer (score 3):

That filter topology is called a narrow-band multiple-feedback (MFB) band-pass filter.

C3 and C4 are both part of the band pass filter and define the pass band frequency range.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the known methods to improve the damping characteristics of a second-order bandpass.

- With the exception of C2, all the other parts resemble the well-known second-order bandpass in multi-feedback-topology.
- The additional capacitor C2 adds an additional lowpass function to the circuit with a pole at app. fp=180 kHz [wp=1/T=1/(12p*75k)]. This effect can be seen in the BODE diagram: The rising slope is +20dB/dec whereas  the falling slope of the magnitude approaches -40dB/dec.